# LINQ Issue anonymous type

Tags: linq

```cs
db.PointCostCentres
    .Join(db.CostCentres, PointCostCentre => PointCostCentre.pcc_CostCentreID, CostCentre => CostCentre.ccn_CostCentreId,
        (pcc, cc) => new { pcc, cc })
    .Where(t => t.pcc.pcc_PointID == accountId && t.cc.ccn_Status == 'A')
    .Join(db.Vehicles, vc => vc.cc.ccn_CostCentreId, Vehicle => Vehicle.veh_CostCentreId,
        (vc, Vehicle) => new { vc, Vehicle })
    .Where(veh => veh.Vehicle.veh_StatusTxt == "Active" || veh.Vehicle.veh_StatusTxt == "On Hold" || veh.Vehicle.veh_StatusTxt == "On Order")
    .Join(db.Vehicles, vcc => vcc.Vehicle.veh_NextFleetNo, Vehi => Vehi.veh_FleetNo,
        (vcc, Vehi) => new { vcc, Vehi })
    .Select(v => 
    {
        CostCentre = v.vc.cc.ccn_CostCentre,
        CostCentreName = v.vc.cc.ccn_CostCentreName,
        CostCentreId = v.vc.cc.ccn_CostCentreId,
        Colour = v.Vehicle.veh_Colour,
        DeliveryDate = v.Vehicle.veh_ReceivedDate,
        Driver = v.Vehicle.veh_Driver,
        FleetID = v.Vehicle.veh_FleetNo,
        Location = v.Vehicle.veh_Location,
        NVIC = v.Vehicle.veh_Nvic,
        Odometer = v.Vehicle.veh_LastKm,
        OdometerDate = v.Vehicle.veh_LastKmDate,
        OrderDate = v.Vehicle.veh_OrderedDate,
        PurchaseOrderNo = v.Vehicle.veh_PurchaseOrder,
        StartKM = v.Vehicle.veh_StartKm,
        Rego = v.Vehicle.veh_RegoNo,
        ReplacementRego = v.Vehicle.veh_PrevRegoNo,
        ReplacementFleetID = v.Vehicle.veh_PrevFleetNo,
        Scheme = v.Vehicle.veh_SAT,
        ServiceDueDate = v.Vehicle.veh_NextSvcDate,
        TransportBookedDate = v.Vehicle.veh_DisplTransBkd,
        LastServiceDate = v.Vehicle.veh_LastSvcDate,
        LastServiceKMs = v.Vehicle.veh_LastSvcKm,
        LastOdoReading = v.Vehicle.veh_LastKm,
        LastOdoReadingDate = v.Vehicle.veh_LastKmDate,
        ServiceIntervalKMs = v.Vehicle.veh_ServiceKm,
        ServiceIntervalMonths = v.Vehicle.veh_ServiceDays,
        VinNumber = v.Vehicle.veh_VinNo

    })
    .ToList();
```

> error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
> Error CS1061 '<anonymous type: <anonymous type: <anonymous type:
> PointCostCentre pcc, CostCentre cc> vc, Vehicle Vehicle> vcc, Vehicle
> Vehi>' does not contain a definition for 'vc' and no accessible
> extension method 'vc' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous
> type: <anonymous type: <anonymous type: PointCostCentre pcc,
> CostCentre cc> vc, Vehicle Vehicle> vcc, Vehicle Vehi>' could be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> WebsiteServices .

Comment: help me in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The two most important questions are :

1. Is it not possible to use navigation properties?
2. Is it not possible to use an editor with code completion or
   intellisense?

Regardless, this may no be a complete answer, but should be enough to help you.

Working backwards your last join is

```
.Join(db.Vehicles, vcc => vcc.Vehicle.veh_NextFleetNo, Vehi => Vehi.veh_FleetNo,
     (c, Vehi) => new { vcc, Vehi })
```

which means that you final result is going to be an anonymous type containing two items name `vcc` and `Vehi`

These are the only two valid options when you write your final select statement , i.e.

```
 .Select(v => { v.
```

and in particular `v.vc` is **not** valid.

Vehi is going to be of type Vehicle and vcc is going to be the result of the previous join which is

```
.Join(db.Vehicles, vc => vc.cc.ccn_CostCentreId, Vehicle => Vehicle.veh_CostCentreId,
    (vc, Vehicle) => new { vc, Vehicle })
```

Again this is going to be an anonymous type containing two items name `vc` and `Vehicle`

Continuing I would guess your first table would be accessible as

```
.Select(v => {   CostCentre  = v.vcc.vc.pcc.ccn_CostCentre ,  )
```

Note, as mentioned, if you have an editor with code completion or intellisense, then all this should be obvious as the editor would show you **only** the correct options.